# $ produces unexpected identifier in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using ${} to call an API from .env
issue is,

my code:

```
const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}'
```

now, `${process.env.API_KEY}` works as apart of string and not as a function or identifier. How can I resolve this?

P.s: I'm new to JS

Comment: Looks like you need the backtick instead of `'`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: While I can see that code not behaving as expected, I can’t see how It can be the cause of that error message. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: I attempted to fix your code formatting. Please revise again if it's not right.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using embedded expressions with ${...}-notation, you need to put them between backticks like: `${...}`

```js
var process = { env: { API_KEY: 'my_app_id' } };

const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric&appid=${process.env.API_KEY}`;

console.log(url);
```